# Pcre2grep multiline regular expression

Tags: regular-expression, pcregrep

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match the first html of a text file with this content:

```
garbage
garbage
§<html class="test1">
<div>test</div></html>§
garbage
garbage
§<html class="test2>
<div>test</div></html>§
garbage
garbage
§<html class="test3">
<div>test</div></html>§
garbage
garbage
```

first I tried something similar on regex101.com

```
<html.*?html>
```

with PCRE2 and single line mode and it works ok. Then I tried it on Windows with Notepad++ with "dot matches new line" option enabled, it works ok there too.

Now I'm trying to do the same on Arch Linux with pcre2grep, i've tried with this regular expression:

```
pcre2grep -o '(?s)<html.*?html>' test.txt
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why because from what i have understood the "(?s)" modifier should enable the PCRE2_DOTALL. How can i create an equivalent regular expression with pcre2grep ?

Comment: Are the  `§` characters intended to represent anything or are the literally in the text?

Comment: AFAIK the `(?s)` modifier only tells the engine to count newlines as `.` characters - you still need the `-M` command line option to enable multi-line matching

Comment: @roaima the § character is part of the text. Thanks @steeldriver with the -M it seems to work (I didn't expect to enable another option to enable the multiline scanning). The complete regex is the following `pcre2grep -Mo -m 1 '(?s)<html.*?html>' test.txt`

Comment: [trying to parse html with regular expressions alone is doomed to failure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/137158).  Use an html or xml parser. and if your html is too broken to be usable with a strict parser like xmlstarlet, write your own in perl using one of the many html parsing libraries. or python if you prefer that.   but trying to do it with a line-oriented tool like grep will, at best, get your something that partially works with your exact current data file but is extremely fragile and will break on even trivial changes to the input data.